# How to iterate a multidimensional json_decoded object in Perl to create a new json object?

Tags: php, json, perl, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to recreate a php process in Perl and am not having much luck ( I don't know much Perl ).

This is my php code:

```
$json = '{"0":{"name":"action","value":"none"},"1":{"name":"additionalTraining","value":"modulesRevisited"},"2":{"name":"additionalTrainingComments","value":""},"3":{"name":"additionalTraining","value":"moduleReporting"},"4":{"name":"additionalTrainingComments","value":""},"5":{"name":"additionalTrainingComments","value":""},"6":{"name":"anotherValue","value":""},"7":{"name":"1359436206","value":""},"8":{"name":"1359436207","value":""},"48":{"name":"actionId","value":""},"49":{"name":"multiSelect","value":"second"},"50":{"name":"multiSelect","value":"third"},"51":{"name":"radio","value":"1"},"52":{"name":"svgs","value":{"0":{"id":"drawing"},"1":{"id":"drawing"}}}}';
$decoded = json_decode($json,true);
$clean = array();
foreach($decoded as $Obj => $array){
    if(array_key_exists($array['name'], $clean))
    {
        if(!is_array($clean[$array['name']]))
        {
            $value = $clean[$array['name']];
            $clean[$array['name']] = array($value,$array['value']);
        }
        else
        {
            array_push($clean[$array['name']], $array['value']);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $clean[$array['name']]=$array['value'];
    }
}
 echo json_encode($clean);
```

**UPDATE:**
This is what I've tried in Perl and the walls I keep hitting:

```
use JSON;
use Data::Dumper;
use warnings;
use strict;
my @records = decode_json($json_text); 
foreach my $element (@records)
{
      print "$element\n";
}
```

I get a hashref.  So I try changing the first line to:

```
my @records = @{ decode_json($json_text) }; #dereference function as it returns an arrayref, not a list
```

Then I get "Not an ARRAY reference" when trying to loop through.

Then I try something like this and get no results or errors:

```
my $records = decode_json($json_text); 
my $i = 0;
my @records;
foreach my $entry (@{$records[0]}) {
    my %listHash = %{$entry};
    my $key;
    my $value;
    $i++;
    while(($key, $value) = each(%listHash)) {   
        my $key;
        my $value;
        print "${key}_$i, $value\n";
    }
}
```

Then I try and combine bits of all of them to get the output I'm after and the closest I come to is:

```
my %records = %{ decode_json($json_text) }; 
while ( my ($key, $value) = each %records )
{
  my $records;
  #print "key: $key, value: $records{$key}\n";
  while ( my ($key, $value) = each %{$value} )
  {
    print "key: $key, value: $value\n";
  }
}
```

But this gives me output like so:

```
key: name, value: anotherValue
key: value, value: third
key: name, value: multiSelect
key: value, value: moduleReporting
```

whereas I need output like

```
key: anotherValue, value: third
key: multiSelect, value: moduleReporting
```

Where am I going wrong?

How can I recreate the same result in Perl?  Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: @HydraIO - Yes, I have and I haven't been able to recreate it, thus posting here for help.  I am using the JSON module, I have decoded the json and tried looping through the array, array hashes but I don't know enough about Perl loops to do it the way I have in php.

Comment: @daxim - I have updated my question with what I have tried.  Hopefully it demonstrates where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you aren't really going wrong; it is just the JSON format that is being as stupid as possible. The JSON is a hash of keys (which are sorted, numeric strings) which map to another level of hashes, which have the keys `name` and `value`:

```
{
  "0": {"name": "someKey",    "value": "someValue"},
  "1": {"name": "anotherKey", "value": "anotherValue"}
}
```

(This data should probably be encoded as `[{"someKey": "someValue"}, {"anotherKey": "anotherValue"}]`.)

So what we'll do is to loop through the numerically sorted keys for the outer hash:

```
for my $index (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %records) { ... }
```

Inside that loop, we do *not* loop through the keys/values of the hash values. Instead, we just pick the values of the keys `name` and `value`:

```
my $record_value = $records{$index};
my ($key, $value) = @$record_value{qw/name value/};   # a "hash slice"
```

and print them:

```
say "key: $key, value: $value";
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I know it's a stupid json structure.  I have to work with it atm :(  I tried your code: `my %records = %{ decode_json($json_text) }; 
for my $index (sort { $a <=> $b } keys %records) {
 my %record;
 my $record_value = $record{$index};
 my ($key, $value) = @$record_value{qw/key value/};
 print "key: $key, value: $value";
}` but I get no data values.  Just lots of these Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at json_test.cgi line 16. and
key: , value: key: , value: key: , value: key: , value: key: , value: key: , value: key:  etc

Comment: @user2535949 I'm terribly sorry, there was a typo: It's `$records{$index}` with an `s`. Oh, and you'll want `print "key: $key, value: $value\n"` with a newline.

Comment: Thank you for that correction!  We are almost there.  I can get the values correctly but the $key is printed blank? Could it be to do with the hash slice?

Comment: @user2535949 Yes, it is `@$record_value{qw/name value/}`. I forgot that the key field was named `name`.

Comment: Excellent, that was it :)  I should be able to recreate the new json from these values now.  Thanks so much.